# how can i fix this subdivision modifier problem?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

[image: this is my wall without modifier]

[image: this is after i add subdivision surface]

i want to add subdivision surface modifier to make brick wall texture more realistic and use displacement

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (the wall only)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i uploaded  how can i share here?
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nWMdNJ1W" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nWMdNJ1W/)

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current topology the *Subdivision Surface* modifier will generate an inner vertex, therefore this problem, you can fix the topology with the *Knife* tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through) and the problem won't occur:

[image]

Comment: it worked thank you